# Python - making a shape with two lines and three asterisks in the middle

Tags: python, ascii-art

I'm supposed to ask the user for a number and print out the following shapes:

user input = 1 (1 unit tall and 1 unit in between the two lines)

```
*****
* * *
*****
```

user input = 2 (2 units tall, 2 units in between)

```
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
```

user input = 3

```
*********
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   *   *
*********
```

and so on...

For now, I get a hollow square with the user input number:

```
side = int(input("Choose a number: "))
inner = side - 2
print ('*' * side)
for i in range(inner):
    print ('*' + ' ' * inner + '*')
print ('*' * side)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: It is now part of the question. Thank you for asking.

Comment: And the output of what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well usually when you want to solve *ASCII-art* problems, you start with analyzing the image. What we see here is that every image:

1. first has a line that has `2*n+3` asterisks;
2. followed by `n` lines that have an asterisk, `n` spaces, an asterisk, `n` spaces and again an asterisk; and
3. a line with `2*n+3` asterisks.

So we can simply make use of the of the fact that a *sequence* (`list`, `str`ing, `tuple`) multiplied by a number is a sequence of the same type that repeats the sequence the given number of times.

So for the first and the last line, we can simply write `'*'*(2*n+3)`. The lines in the middle can be constructed with `'*'+' '*n+'*'+' '*n+'*'` and we need to repeat that `n` times. So we can construct a list of the lines with:

```
['*'*(2*n+3)]+['*'+' '*n+'*'+' '*n+'*']*n+['*'*(2*n+3)]
# ^ first     ^ middle line               ^ last line
```

And then use `'\n'.join(..)` to join the lines together:

```
def print_pattern(n):
    print('\n'.join(['*'*(2*n+3)]+['*'+' '*n+'*'+' '*n+'*']*n+['*'*(2*n+3)]))
```

This generates:

```
>>> print_pattern(1)
*****
* * *
*****
>>> print_pattern(2)
*******
*  *  *
*  *  *
*******
>>> print_pattern(3)
*********
*   *   *
*   *   *
*   *   *
*********
>>> print_pattern(4)
***********
*    *    *
*    *    *
*    *    *
*    *    *
***********
>>> print_pattern(5)
*************
*     *     *
*     *     *
*     *     *
*     *     *
*     *     *
*************
```

You can also make it more precedural (although that is usually considered less Pythonic) by using a `for` loop:

```
def print_pattern(n):
    print('*'*(2*n+3))
    for _ in range(n):
        print('*'+' '*n+'*'+' '*n+'*')
    print('*'*(2*n+3))
```

Or in a program with user input:

```
def print_pattern(n):
    print('*'*(2*n+3))
    for _ in range(n):
        print('*'+' '*n+'*'+' '*n+'*')
    print('*'*(2*n+3))
n = int(input("Eliga un número: "))
print_pattern(n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm trying to use the code with the for loop but the image isn't showing. Do you know what I might be doing wrong? I set 'n 'equal to the user input number.

Comment: @IreneCastañeda: can you update the question with your loop code?

Comment: @IreneCastañeda: see updated answer. You forgot to *call* the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things your program needs to do. First, you need to calculate the length of the top and bottom lines. This is 3 + 2 * (number from user), because there will be 3 asterisks and 2 gaps, with each gap being the same length as the number that the user inputted.

Then you need to use loops. First print out the number of asterisks from the number you calculated above. Then use a loop to print out the asterisks and spaces. You can make each iteration of the loop to print a single line, so the loop is just used to print out the correct number of lines. Then print the final line that matches the first line of asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
m = 6
n = 2
for i in range(m*n+(m-n)):
    print '*',

print
for c in range(m):
    for i in range(m):
        print "*",
        for b in range(n):
            print ' ',

     print

for i in range(m*n+(m-n)):
print '*',

print
```

Answer (score 0):

I used format() to generalize

```
def ascing(n, C, patmid = "*{0: <{gap}}*{0: <{gap}}*\n" ):
    mid = (n * patmid).format(' ', gap=n)
    print( "{0}\n{1}{0}".format((3+2*n)*C, mid) )


for x in range(1,7):
    ascing(x, '*')
    print("\n====================\n")
```